# How to create a stream of OGG pages with headers?

Tags: c++, encoding, audio-streaming, ogg, opus

I have a stream of PCM data (16bit - stereo) & need to convert it into stream of OGG pages with respective streaming headers (version/ header type/ pattern/ checksum/ etc.,). After that it will be sent via WebSocket to my server, which will decode it back to PCM using the API [DecodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData)

New to opus library.
So any help will be appreciated.

- Environment: windows
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019
- Language used: c++
- Bit architecture: 32-bit

Comment: https://gitlab.xiph.org/xiph/opus/-/blob/master/doc/trivial_example.c